# Creating ranges of values form single numbers in django-filters from using 'method='

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am trying to create a value range filter in my application using django-filters. In my database are invidual vields with age (that were created using models.IntegerField).

I want to add now check box like this below:
[image]

Everything is almost ready but I do not know how to reach the database. I read documentation about '[Customize filtering with Filter.method'](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method) and how use [RangeFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method) but I still do not know how to create the right condition. How can I do this in my stytuation (how create condition for my 'requirements=?') which returns a value, for example, between 20-30 ?

We have a view in the documentation:

```
f = F({'price_min': '5', 'price_max': '15'}, queryset=qs)
```

What is 'f'? where in this situation the condition reaching the database?

**My filters.py**

```
from .models import Promoters
import django_filters


class PromotersFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    CHOICES = (
        ('age_option1', '0-20'),
        ('age_option2', '21-30'),
        ('age_option3', '31-40'),
        ('age_option4', '41-50'),
        ('age_option5', '50+'),
    )

    age_list = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(label='Age list', choices=CHOICES, method='filter_by_order')

    class Meta:
        model = Promoters
        fields = ['age', 'profession', 'sex', 'city']

    def filter_by_order(self, queryset, name, value):
        requirements = **??**

        return queryset.order_by(requirements)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a helper function as follows:

```
def get_age_range(option):
  if option == 'age_option1':
    return 0, 20
  elif option == 'age_option2':
    return 21, 30
  ...... and so on
```

then call this function in your view.

```
lower, upper = get_age_range(selected option)

queryset.filter(max_price>lower).filter(max_price<higher)
```

haven't tested this. Like you said django filter may be able to do it in sofasticated way. but this is one way to go about it.